# Solr Suggest Configuration and Improvement

Tags: search, solr, autocomplete, lucene, autosuggest

I would like to know if Solr suggestions improve with every search attempt. If not is there a method to do so. I tried configuring Solr suggester but doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. Ive tried everything I could find out, so far I'm not making any progress.

Examples say setting the Solr config and all did as they had mentioned ( in Solr Wiki ) but still couldn't get Suggest to work. Im using Solr 4.7, is this a version issu?

Here is the fields that I attempt to use for suggestion

```
<field name="suggestions" type="suggest_text" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<fieldType name="suggest_text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="hitad_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="20" minGramSize="1"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Can someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: may i know why you included Elasticsearch in your question??

Comment: People who have tried Solr may have also used Elastic search. I hope that is reasonable enough to include Elastic search as a tag.

So do you have any idea about the question I had posted or was this your biggest question?

Comment: they are different configurations..Please remove the tag..!